# Java native library invokes another DLL and doesn't search in java.library.path

Tags: java, native, java-3d

I want to deploy a .war in Tomcat that ships with its Java3D DLLs and a DirectX software renderer. My problem is that the invocation of the DirectX DLL is done in Java3D's native code, and it doesn't know the `java.library.path`, nor searches at Tomcat's `\bin` or `\lib`. It only finds if I put the DLL at the client's Window's `PATH`, for example at `JAVA_HOME`.

Is there any way to configure my deployment (maybe a script that rewrites Window's `PATH`) or Java3D (Their documented properties are [here](http://java.net/projects/java3d/pages/Java3DApplicationDev)) to find the DLL in my installation directory?

Comment: what do you mean by rewrites? to set the value for the PATH property? or to add a path to the PATH property? or do you want to dynamically copy the dlls to windows PATH variable during deployment?

Comment: Add a path to the PATH property was a first option, but I would prefer to copy the DLL at the PATH, if it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify additional JVM properties in the Tomcat startup script.

You'll want to make sure that java.library.path points to the appropriate location for the DLLs.